# Day of week in digital clock plasmoid

Tags: 11.10, kubuntu, kde, plasma

I have problem with configuring digital clock plasmoid: i can't display day of week in it. As far as i remember it was simle in previous distr versions. Will be glad for help. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Default plasma widget digital clock**

Right click the plasma-widget > Digital clock settings > Date format.

Long date has the weekday at here.

**More options**

plasma-widget-adjustableclock

```
:~$ apt-cache show plasma-widget-adjustableclock

Description: an adjustable clock Plasma widget
 This Plasma widget shows date and time in adjustable format using
 rich text.
Homepage: http://www.kde-look.org/content/show.php/Adjustable+Clock?content=92825
```

[image]